# Ruby Newbie: Confused About Boolean Logic

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

I have an array, if I find a value in it, I want to execute a block of code. Also, if the array is nil, I want to execute that block. So the code I tried is:

```
if !array.respond_to? :index || array.index(str)
  #some code
```

So if it's nil it's true, or if str is somewhere in the array, it's true, right? But if it finds the item at index 0, it doesn't enter the block. Also, according to irb `false || 0` evalueates to `0`. WTF?? I thought that everything was true except false and nil. I guess || does something odd that I'm not expecting??

My questions are: What's going on? What's a nice way to write a conditional that does what I want?

Comment: You just said it yourself: "I thought that everything was true except false and nil." So why are you surprised that false || 0 is 0?

Comment: I'm surprised that false || 0 != true. 0 isn't false or nil, so that should be false || true = true. Why isn't it?

Comment: @pseudopeach Because 0 is truthy, and that's how Ruby works.

Comment: @Dave Newton "Truthy" is obviously ill-defined for the poster. Perhaps you would do better to define and explain, instead of saying "that's how Ruby works."

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop It was explained yesterday; redundant.

Comment: @psuedopeach In short, boolean logic operators like `||` work a little like a coalesce operation.

Comment: I wonder if Ruby is interpreting `:index || array.index(str)` as the entire argument to `respond_to`. Try putting parentheses around `:index` and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
if array.nil? || array.member?(s)
    # ...
```

`false || 0` evaluates to `0` because it's an `or`. False isn't truthy (obviously ;) but 0 is, so the expression is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) and [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) with an inline `if` seems most idiomatic to me.

```
#your code if arr.nil? || arr.include?(str)
```

Comment: I like your code better, but I still don't get why false or 0 is 0.

Comment: @pseudopeach A Ruby "or" will return the first truthy value it finds, in this case, 0.

Comment: A 'truthy' expression is true in a boolean context.

Comment: Specifically, in Ruby, everything but `false` and `nil` is truthy.

Comment: So if (false || 0) is truthy, why didn't my IF block execute?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for a nil array or an empty one? If you've already declared the array it won't be nil even if it's empty. I'd write it like:

```
if array.empty? || array.include(str)
```

or if you really want to check for a nil array:

```
if array.nil? || array.include(str)
```

I'd use .include rather than .index to avoid getting a 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
if array.nil?­ || array­.member?(str­)
    #code block
end
```

The || operator almost reminds you of a coalesce.

Given a = false, b = :bacon

```
return a || b #returns :bacon
```